# How to use jquery keypress event to hide match or starting class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, keypress

First of all Sorry for my poor English. I am not jQuery expert
I am trying a real time search query for my app. So I m trying and failing... :(

pls check the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#test" ).keypress(function( event ) {
        var $gettag = $("#test").val();
        $('p[class^="tr"]').hide(1000);                      
        
        //$('p[class^="tr"]').hide(1000);  its works fine
    });
});
```

```html
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test" value="Mickey Mouse"></p>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p class="try">This is another small paragraph.</p>
<p class="tiy">iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiThis is another small paragraph.</p>
```

I want to hide the class of p what type on the input box. 
hope can get help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code already hides the `p` tags containing `tr` on `keypress` class. What else did you expect it to do?

Comment: hi  doutriforce, I want to hide the 'P' tag with 'try' class

Comment: Your code is already doing that. If you want to hide _only_ elements containing "try" class, your selector should be `$('.try')`.

Comment: I am using a var which getting from input keypress event. when it will match it will hide.

Comment: Match the whole class name?

Comment: whole or first 1-2 letter...

Comment: hi doutriforce, I got it.   `$( "#test" ).on('input', function() {
        var gettag = $("#test").val();
        $('p[class^="'+gettag+'"]').show();                      
        
    });`  is worked for me

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you well, you need to hide the `p` elements according to the input text.

So, if i type "try" it should hide the `p` tag that haves "try" class.

See if the code below does what you're asking.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").on('keyup', function(event) {
    var value = $("#test").val();

    if (value.length > 1) {
    debugger;
      var $element = $('p[class*="' + value + '"]');

      if ($element.length == 0) {
        $('p').show(1000);
      } else {
        $element.hide(1000);
      }
    } else {
      $('p').show(1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test" value="Mickey Mouse"></p>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p class="try test">This is another small paragraph.</p>
<p class="tiy">iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiThis is another small paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: thanks doutriforce, you are the life saver. thanks a lot

Comment: it's work fine for the one class but if a div have multiple like `<p class="try anotherclass">This is a paragraph.</p>` class it isn;t work. how I can overcome bro

Comment: I have updated the answer. Changed the wildcard from `^=` to `*=`.